# Allowing only a single checkbox to be checked is a datatable with a checkbox column?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables to show some tabular data with a checkbox column as the first column.

```
<div>
    <table style="width:100%" id="resultsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    Approve
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
function BindData() {
    $('#resultsTable').DataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "/Jumbo/GetallResults",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bStateSave": true, 
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sName": "",
            "sClass": "checkbox-column",
            "mRender": function () {
                return ' <input type="checkbox" />';
            }
        },{
            "sName": "Colors",
            "bSortable": true,
            "mRender": function (data,type, full) {
                return '<span title=\"' + full[0] + '\">' + full[0] + '</span>';
            }
        }]
    });
}

$('#resultsTable').on('change','.check', function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('#resultsTable').find('.check');
    var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(function() { return this.checked; });
});
```

That renders a grid in which each row has a checkbox in the first column.

I need a way to make it work in such a way that at any given instance only one checkbox is allowed to be checked.

Can someone guide me through this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use a `radio` button?

Comment: The powers that be want a checkbox

Comment: Still there, please check out my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a minimal example.

```js
$(function () {
  $("input").change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("input").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }  
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Item 1</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Item 2</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Item 3</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Item 4</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"> Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your datatable

```
   columnDefs: [ {
           orderable: false,
           className: 'select-checkbox',
           targets:   0
       } ],
       select: {
           style:    'os',
           selector: 'td:first-child'
       },
      "aoColumns": [
       {"mData": "id", "mRender" : function(data) { return "";} },
       {"mData": "name"},
       {"mData": "age" },
       {"mData": "gender"},

     ],
```

For getting selected Data:

```
 var oTable = $('#yourTableId').dataTable();
      $('#yourTableId tbody tr').each(function(index,elem){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
            var aData = oTable._('tr')[index];

         }
     });
```

HTML

```
                   <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th width="10%"></th>
                        <th width="25%">Name</th>
                        <th width="20%" >Age</th>
                        <th width="45%" >Gender</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
```